# When does a constexpr static member stop being a constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, if-constexpr

I have this snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct JustStr {
    JustStr(const std::string& x) : val(x) {}
    static constexpr bool pred = false;
    std::string val;
};

template <typename T>
class C {
 private:
    T x;
 public:
    C(T x_) : x(x_) {}
    void f() {
        if constexpr (!x.pred) {
                std::cout << x.val << std::endl;
            }
    }

};

template<typename T>
void f2(T x) {
    T y(x);
    if constexpr (!y.pred) {
            std::cout << x.val << std::endl;
        }
}

int main() {
    C<JustStr> c(JustStr("yes"));
    c.f();  // Fails
    f2(JustStr("yes"));  // Succeeds
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: shouldn't `c.f();` and `f2(JustStr("yes"));` fail or succeed simultaneously? Why does the one fail and why does the other succeed?

Comment: `pred` id `static`; `x` isn't

Comment: I am guessing "id" means "is". So if I understand correctly if `x` is not static then none of it's members are. So are they all copied in `C`?

Comment: No, sorry; today I'm out of tune; ignore my comment (and yes, it was "is" not "id"; sorry again).

Comment: Sure (c++ and Fridays don't mix well :P )

Comment: Good Idea: I'll try to blame the friday :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [list of things](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) that prevent an expression from being considered as a core constant expression.

One of the things you cannot do is evaluate:

> `this`, except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor that is being evaluated as part of `e`;

In `f()`, we're evaluating `this` in order to see what `x.pred` is (because really it's `this->x.pred`), but `f()` isn't a constexpr function. So this bullet point rules out `c.f()`. If `f()` *were* `constexpr`, then this would compile.

In `f2()`, we're not evaluating `this` anywhere, so that bullet doesn't apply. We do an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, but it does refer to a [complete non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2.7.1). Nothing else applies.  So it's okay.